# ASP.NET Login Controls, page postback and rendering on logout

Tags: asp.net, authentication, postback

I'm a bit puzzled by the behavior of the default ASP.NET [Authentication controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx), by its lifecycle to be precise.

In my `MasterPage`, I added a `LoginView` Control which displays the nice [Login] or [Logout] links. When I am logged in and click on [logout], I set up the control to perform a redirection to the homepage of the application.

Internally, when a click on "logout" happens, a postback is triggered. The following steps happen (among others of course):

1. The page that fired the postback is reinitialized
2. The page that fired the postback is reloaded
3. The LoggingOut event is fired
4. The LoggedOut event is fired
5. The page that fired the postback is PreRendered
6. The redirection happens
7. The target page is loaded (LoggedOut.aspx in my case)

On most of the pages, this works fine. But some pages expect some data to be initialized for their rendering to happens correctly. When this loggout postback occurs, the data isn't correctly initialized, but the page is still PreRendered which leads to some... "unexpected behavior" >_<

My question is thus twofold:

- Why does this rendering step happens since the page won't be displayed at all?
- Is there a way to prevent the rendering to happen?

Thanks a lot.
Tim

PS: here's a small VS2010 sample project showing you the call sequence & page lifecycle if you want to try it out for yourself http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11764136/LoginTest.7z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Venemo's answer gave me an idea that seems to be working.

Instead of relying on the `LoginStatus` component to perform the redirection, I registered the MasterPage hosting the `LoginStatus` components to the `LoginStatus.LoggedOut` event and fire the redirection *"per hand"* before the PreRender step can be called.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MasterLoginStatus.LoggedOut += new EventHandler(OnUserLoggedOut);
}

private void OnUserLoggedOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Response.Redirect("~/LoggedOut.aspx", true);
}
```

I was concerned the `LoginStatus` component might remain *dirty* by doing this but sofar I haven't found any issue with it e.g. "works until proven otherwise".

Remains the question of "why the component behaves like this" but I guess it was a design decision that will remain unanswered.

Edit: this works fine until you get the same problem for the "login" action. Haven't found a way around this one yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to prevent the actual rendering of the page.

Stop processing the current request when you redirect the page. This can be done by giving a true parameter to the Response.Redirect method:

```
Response.Redirect("http://somewhere", true);
```

You can also do this manually by calling Response.Close();

Comment: If I was performing the redirection myself yes, but in this case, the Login control is doing it for me via the FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage() method so I have no control whatsoever on the Response.Redirect() that is happening.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to hack around this, but this is how the login control works

Comment: @Tim - maybe you could try to implement your own "login control" in which you can control the redirect. I can help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using if(!isPostBack) test to control what should be rendered/re-initialized and what shouldn't?

Comment: In CodeBehind, yes everywhere. Unfortunately, the fun starts when my aspx pages try to access a class (page) property via `<%= this.CurrentProject.Note %>` for instance.

Comment: '<%= this.CurrentProject.Note %>' is inline code which is not controlled by the isPostBack in your code behind... I would always keep logic in code behind rather than inline

Comment: Yes, you're right, that's actually the way I've been going around the original issue until now. But I'm still wondering why it's like that ; because it does not make any sense to render the page just to leave it right after...

Answer (score 0):

I've got a serious problem with a DevExpress control (The report DocumentMap) which sometimes requests the whole report, bypassing the caching mechanism, when the end-user clicks on the logout link on the LoginStatus control. I've tried a lot of approaches to stop dead the "logout" postback so that the report won't get generated (some reports took 5 minutes to render, so the logout action sometimes took that long). I think this is similar to your problem: you don't want to do any heavy processing if the user is logging out. So I've tried a different approach: why didn't I recognize that the postback is indeed a logging out postback? All my pages inherit from a base page, so I've set this code in the base page:

```
public bool IsLoggingOut { get; private set; }

protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreInit(e);
    var eventTarget = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
    IsLoggingOut = eventTarget != null && eventTarget.Contains("HeadLoginView$HeadLoginStatus");
}
```

Now all I need to do in my page is to surround any heavy processing with a test of !IsLoggingOut... You could even do you redirect to the LoggedOut page without having to handle any events, just like this:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{ 
    if (IsLoggingOut)
        Response.Redirect("~/LoggedOut.aspx", true);
}
```

Even if you prefer to use the event handler to do that redirect, being able to know that the postback is indeed due to a logout click is a nice thing!

Comment: This is what I'm looking for but it doesn't seem to work as eventTarget always equals "".

Comment: @David maybe you're not using a postback... Without more information it will be hard to figure out why it is not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was having this problem with the [LoginStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginstatus(v=vs.110).aspx) control.  I can't see why it is a useful design to post back and `Render` the page when the user has clicked "logout".  Through some tests, I found that I had to let the page go through its entire lifecycle, so `Reponse.End()` and `Response.Transfer()` did not work.

My solution was to add event handlers for the LoginStatus `LoggedOut` event, and then override the `Render()` method in the master page to do *nothing* if the user has logged out.  I actually had the LoginStatus nested inside a user control that was then in the master page, so I had to bubble the event.

In my user control containing the `LoginStatus` control, I added an event handler for the `LoggedOut` event. In the UserStatus.aspx file:

```
<asp:LoginStatus runat="server" ID="loginStatusDefault" OnLoggedOut="loginStatusDefault_LoggedOut" ... />
```

Then in the code-behind:

```
public event EventHandler LoggedOut;
protected void loginStatusDefault_LoggedOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.LoggedOut != null)
     this.LoggedOut(sender, e);
}
```

Now in the master page default.master, I have already included the UserStatus control:

```
<c:userstatus ID="ctlUserStatus" runat="server" />
```

and in the code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ctlUserStatus.LoggedOut += ctlUserStatus_LoggedOut;

    ...
}

bool IsLoggedOut { get; set; }

void ctlUserStatus_LoggedOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IsLoggedOut = true;
}

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    if (!IsLoggedOut)
        base.Render(writer);
}
```

For me, the page rendering is what was bombing out when the user clicked "logout", so this took care of the problem for all pages.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was have the logout link or onloggingout control just redirect to another page, "Logout.aspx" which then handles the log out code. Works great actually.

```
protected void LoginStatus1_LoggingOut(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {

            Response.Redirect("~/Logout.aspx");
        }
```